# How can I use the "gemspec" rule in Bundler, while still using a local checkout of a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Scenario: I am developing a gem `gem-foo`, using Bundler. I have a dependency on `gem-bar`, which I have checked out locally for development. I can declare this dependency in the `Gemfile` as:

```
gem "gem-bar", :path => "/path/to/local/gem-bar"
```

However, when developing a gem the "best practice" seems to be to define the required gems in the `gem-foo.gemspec` via:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'gem-bar'
```

and then simply include the dependencies in the `Gemfile` using:

```
gemspec
```

What I would like to do is to add the runtime dependency on the gem in the gemspec, but make some local modifications to `gem-bar` and have a `bundle install` use the local development checkout. Assume the case where I control both gems, and am hacking on them somewhat concurrently, and I'll be pushing the new versions simultaneously. I *could* just comment out the `s.add_runtime_dependency` in the gemspec and add it with the local path in the Gemfile, but that feels... error-prone? The gemspec *should* always declare this dependency, and the Gemfile should be able to override the location Bundler should use for the gem. However, if you actually do this, you get the following error:

> You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources. You specified that gem-bar (>= 0) should come from an unspecfied source and source at /path/to/local/gem-bar

Ideally, I'd just have some sort of local override, since I never want the case where I accidentally push the gem with the requirement of a local `gem-bar` at a specific path. That would be dumb.

Does anyone have a good solution to this use case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few people have found this problem, Yehuda Katz has said he would happily accept a patch: http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-bundler/browse_thread/thread/d4215c4930a63ffc?pli=1

As the best workaround, comment out the gemspec line in your gemfile and suffer some duplication?

**Update:**

It looks like you don't have to wait - https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/commit/03378109d

The commit message:
"Make it possible to override a .gemspec dependency's source in the Gemfile"

hooray!

Answer (score 2):

For now, what I've done is to disable gem requirements in the gemspec when a given environment variable is set, then in the Gemfile, add a gem definition that points to my local filesystem.

I wrote about my whole workflow here: http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2010/07/28/bundler-to-the-max/
Note: I also use jeweler, which complicates things greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Boy! I never get to these on time do I? Try Bundler options like --something vendor I can't remember.

Comment: To install to "vendor/bundle", do `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`. Once it's installed there, and you have a Gemfile.lock, you can also use `bundle install --deployment` for non-development environments.

Comment: Okay! That's what I remember. Thanks. Was tired when I posted it and only used it a few times. I'm just investigating rbenv these days. Seems to be pretty straight forward. Yehuda Katz wrote up some pretty good stuff about which way to go with this issue. Best practice as of gem development and all.